# Jordan's Decomposition Theorem in Real Analysis

Tags: analysis

Define $f(x)$ = $\sin x$ on $[0, 2\pi]$. Find two increasing functions $h$ and $g$ for which $f = h - g$ on $[0, 2\pi$].

I started this problem by using $f(x)=[f(x)+TV(f[0,x])]-TV(f[0,x])$. And I tried defining $h(x)=\sin x+TV(f[0,x])$ and $g(x)=TV(f[0,x])$. But $\sin x$ is not an increasing function. And idea on how to make this better?

Comment: What do you mean by $TV$ ?

Comment: TV means total variation.

Answer (score 3):

How about $h(x) = \sin x + 2x$ and $g(x) = 2x$. Both are increasing as

$$h'(x) = \cos x + 2 \geq 1$$

Comment: thanks so much. That works. So do I still define $h(x)=f(x)+TV[0,x]$ as $h(x)=sinx+2x$. Are they both the same? Just wondering.

Comment: I don't know what $TV$, total variation, means here. $h$ and $g$ do what you ask. However, if you need something else, please clarify with more details.